# Computability: Proving a predicate is not recursively enumerable

Tags: predicate-logic, recursion, computability

Let P(p) <=>  for each x, comp(p,x) is defined.

Can anyone explain to me how to prove that P is not RE (recursively enumerable) ?

Comment: If you don't get responses here, you may have better luck on https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What is comp(p,x) ?